# What is the replacement for ActionController::Base.relative_url_root?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am porting a 2.x rails app to rails3; we'll call it foo-app. Foo-app is one section of a larger rails app and lives at main_rails_app.com/foo-app. Previously we just set up the following in our foo-app production config to ensure that our foo-app routes worked properly:

```
ActionController::Base.relative_url_root = "/foo-app"
```

However, with rails3, I now get:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: ActionController::Base.relative_url_root is ineffective. Please stop using it.
```

I have since changed the config entry to the following:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/foo-app"
```

This mostly works in that all calls to external resources (javascript/css/images) will use /foo-app. However, none of my routes change appropriately, or put another way, foo-app root_path gives me '/' when I would expect '/foo-app'.

Two questions:

1. What is the replacement for ActionController::Base.relative_url_root
2. if it is config.action_controller.relative_url_root, then why are my routes not reflecting the relative_url_root value I set?

Comment: Does config.action_controller.relative_url_root still work for you in the latest rails 3 final release? Seems broken for me.

Comment: You are missing 'do'
scope "/context_root" do ...
end

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should be able to handle all that within the routes.rb file.  Wrap all your current routes in scope; for instance.

```
scope "/context_root" do
   resources :controller
   resources :another_controller
   match 'welcome/', :to => "welcome#index"
   root :to => "welcome#index"
end
```

You can then verify your routing via the `rake routes` they should show your routes accordingly, including your context root(relative_url_root)

Comment: Hey Dax, thanks for the reply. I found this same solution a couple of days before you posted it back on 7-21, but having your post confirms I did/found the right solution. Thanks.

Comment: This is helpful, but then how do you apply it differently for your development environment versus your production environment?  My development environment needn't be behind a reverse proxy like the production environment is.

Comment: @tobinjim I found that I needed to set the `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT` environment variable in addition to wrapping my routes in a scope. I then used `scope ENV['RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT'] || '/' do` so that localhost:3000 still works in development without the /context_root.

Comment: @aNoble seems like that's about the right way to go. Here's another example: https://github.com/dre3k/rails3_fcgi/blob/master/config/routes.rb (he sets his RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT in .htaccess, for example)

Comment: What if you don't want to put the prefix in your config/routes, but it depends on your environment?

For example, I have a /rails and /rails-staging prefix for my single domain name: each one is proxied to a different Rails cluster.

I just set config.relative_url_root in my config/environments/*.rb etc to help me manage all that, and the url's just worked.  It was a nice per-environment url prefix that's now gone :-(

Comment: @DanielTsadok you could define a variable in `config/application.rb` that gets its value from the environment (e.g `prefix = ENV['PREFIX']`). Then use this variable to define the scope in `config/routes.rb` (e.g. `scope prefix do ...`).

Answer (score 13):

If you deploy via Passenger, use the `RackBaseURI` directive: http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#RackBaseURI

Otherwise, you can wrap the `run` statement in your `config.ru` with the following block:

```
map ActionController::Base.config.relative_url_root || "/" do
  run FooApp::Application
end
```

Then you only have to set the environment variable `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT` to "/foo-app". This will even apply to routes set in gems or plugins.

Warning: do not mix these two solutions.

Answer (score 6):

I feel like I must be over-complicating this and/or missing something, but this issue has been frustrating me for a while now, and here are my notes.

## Summary

There are two separate issues with two points each for dynamic and static routes:

1. how to get routing to correctly match an incoming URL

   - for routes
   - for static files
2. how to generate URLs that include the relative_root

   - via url helpers
   - for static assets

One way to solve all four points:

- Configure Nginx to strip the `relative_root` portion

  - This solves route matching; just write routes expecting URLs at `/` like development
  - Also static files are served as in development
- Set `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT` environment variable

  - This solves generated static asset helpers
- Use the `ScriptName` middleware below (modify it to use the value from the environment)

  - This solves generated url helpers, e.g. `users_path`

## Wrapping the Rails application in Rack::URLMap in config.ru (Christoph's answer)

```
# config.ru
map '/relative_root' do
  run Myapp::Application
end
```

- requires incoming URL contain the relative_url_root (Nginx can be configured to remove or retain this; see below)
- Rack appends the relative_url_root to the Rack env `SCRIPT_NAME` [rack/urlmap.rb:62](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.5.2/lib/rack/urlmap.rb#L62)
- Rails adds the current request's `SCRIPT_NAME` to url_for options [metal/url_for.rb:41](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.2/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/url_for.rb#L41)
- Rails' url_for prepends the script name when generating paths [routing/url_for.rb:133](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.2/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb#L133)

So that covers URLs generated by the url helpers, e.g. given `UserController`, `users_path` will be prefixed by the relative url root.

## Set SCRIPT_NAME in middleware

```
# config.ru
class ScriptName
  def initialize(app, name)
    @app = app
    @name = name
  end

  def call(env)
    env['SCRIPT_NAME'] += @name
    @app.call(env)
  end
end

use ScriptName, '/relative_root'
run Rails.application
```

- Has same effect as above, but
- Requires that incoming URL NOT contain the relative_url_root

## Setting RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT

- value is saved in `app.config.relative_url_root` [configuration.rb:41](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.2/railties/lib/rails/application/configuration.rb#L41)
- which in turn affects asset paths [asset_url_helper.rb:137](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v4.0.2/actionpack/lib/action_view/helpers/asset_url_helper.rb#L137)
- but that's it as far as I see
- notably does not affect url helpers

## Setting `config.action_controller.relative_url_root`

- ?? May affect assets compilation?
- Overrides RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT env var?

## Explicitly defining all routes under `/relative_root` (rizzah's answer)

```
# config/routes.rb
Myapp::Application.routes.draw do
  scope '/relative_root' do
    ...
  end
end
```

- Url helpers will generate correct urls
- Incoming URL must contain the relative url root (sensitive to Nginx configuration, see below), else "no route matches" exceptions
- URLs requesting static assets, e.g. `/relative_root/images/logo.png` will result in "no route matches" exceptions. This may not be an issue if nginx is serving static assets anyway.

## Nginx config

Given a config like this:

```
upstream myapp {
  server localhost:3000;
}

server {
  ...
  location /relative_root {
    proxy_pass http://myapp/;
  }
}
```

Nginx will strip out the `/relative_root`, and the Rails app will not see it. If you need the Rails app so see it, one way is to change the `proxy_pass` line:

```
...
    proxy_pass http://myapp/relative_root/;
...
```

Comment: To prevent stripping `/relative_root` by Nginx, you can also use `proxy_pass http://myapp;` (lack of trailing slash).