# resource_url generating wrong url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, routes

I have a rails app in a subdirectory of my server, something like www.domain.com/sub
I need to send an url by e-mail, so I tried to use "resource_url" but it generates a link like www.domain.com/resource_path, where should be wwww.domain.com/sub/resource_path.

How can I solve this ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 2.3.8 you can add a line like this to your `config/environments/production.rb`

```
ActionController::Base.relative_url_root = "/sub"
```

I am not sure what the equivalent is for Rails 3, but see this question if that is what you are using: 
[What is the replacement for ActionController::Base.relative_url_root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181746/what-is-the-replacement-for-actioncontrollerbase-relative-url-root)

Comment: It didn't seems to work. All paths become something like www.domain.com/subdomain/subdomain/resource, and the path generated by the resource_url is still wrong. Thanks for your answer.