# Route Temproray URL to controller and Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I am deploying a rails application. At the moment I am having a temporary URL. Can someone guide me how do I go about routing this to my controller and action ??

The temporary URL is http://50.22.41.167/~aromaper/

I tried doing something like this but it is not working :

```
match "~aromaper" , :to => 'front#index'
```

**Here is the error message from the production.log file:**

```
Started GET "/~aromaper/" for 223.29.232.108 at 2011-09-01 22:03:11
-0500   Processing by ContentController#show as HTML   Parameters: {"path"=>"~aromaper"} Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 2ms Rendered public/404.html (0.0ms)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181746/what-is-the-replacement-for-actioncontrollerbase-relative-url-root

Comment: @iafonov : Not sure if this is going to serve the purpose but lets see if I can use it in my case. Thank you for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was make the routes like this :

```
match "/" , :to => "front#index"
```

Worked like a charm.