# Deploying rails 3.1 app in subdirectory

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, unicorn, subdirectory

I'm trying to deploy my rails 3.1.3 app in a subdirectory on the server:
Apache (reverse proxy) => unicorn (listening on localhost:5000)

The problem is with url_helper.
via the --path switch in unicorn I'm setting my /subdir
It gets picked up by rails; DashboardController.config.relative_url_root gives me that subdir.

But when I use something like 'members_path' in my view it gives me '/members' and not '/subdir/members'

what am I missing?

Comment: Any solutions to this? Seems like an obvious and important use-case, yet I have exactly the same problem, and haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem. Two things were missing/faulty in my setup.

1. My web-server had an superflous, faiulty rewrite-rule, rewriting `/prefix/<controller>` to just `/controller`.
2. It seems Rails3 routing are by default ignoring `relative_url_root`. (Stupid IMHO) There's a good tip in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5457484/103192 that shows a trick to make it work again.

> Otherwise, you can wrap the run statement in your config.ru with the
>   following block:
>
> ```
> map ActionController::Base.config.relative_url_root || "/" do
>   run FooApp::Application
> end
> ```

I now have it working much like one would want it to work.