# RoR link_to and assets paths

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, iis-7, iis-7.5, helicontech

I have a RoR (1.9.3 - 3.2) application running on IIS 7.5 over the HeliconZoo Module.
It is located in a sub directory like http://server/application/

Now if i use link_to with a direct location like <% link_to "/users" %> it is linked back to http://server/users instead of http://server/application/users (while linking to a controller action works fine).

Also (which is the bigger problem here) the application is precompiling all assets into server/application/public/assets but is searching for them in server/public/assets when rendering.
If i set config.assets.prefix the assets are also being rendered to a different location ("/application/..." as addition everytime) which results in a constant desync and assets are never being loaded.
I can workaround this by changing config.assets.prefix to "/application/public/assets" for precompile and changing it back to default after, but this is pretty annoying.

Is there some kind of config to tell the render to add a prefix ("/application") on direct links and assets?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used either IIS or HeliconZoo for Rails deployment, so this might not work, but I'll take a crack at answering anyhow, as it seems to me what you're really trying to do is get Rails to understand you're deploying it to a subfolder, and that isn't too difficult. Simply encapsulate everything in your `routes.rb` inside a scope, like so:

```
scope "/context_root" do
   resources :controller
   resources :another_controller
   match 'welcome/', :to => "welcome#index"
   root :to => "welcome#index"
end
```

I copied this answer directly from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181746/what-is-the-replacement-for-actioncontrollerbase-relative-url-root), which might provide more useful information to you.

Comment: When doing this the assets are being loaded correctly, but rails expects the rest of the application to be at /server/application/application where obviously is nothing, so i get an 404 error every time.

Answer (score 0):

Please try and open IIS Manager, navigate to the “application” folder, open context menu and select “Convert to Application”. Normally no specific tinkering with Ruby code required.

Comment: Does not work. I have tried almost all settings on IIS, nothing seem to work.
The Controller actions are linked with "application/" prefix so i guess IIS assumes the application to be in the root, thats why direct links always go into the root of the web page instead of the application. Cannot understand why...