# Rails routing in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

Moving rails app to production and running into the routing issues.  I've read this answer:

[What is the replacement for ActionController::Base.relative_url_root?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181746/what-is-the-replacement-for-actioncontrollerbase-relative-url-root)

but am still having problems understanding the complete solution, and also, how to continue to develop without caring where the app gets placed.

I am running the app at: `http://dev.mycompany.com:8081/myapp/`

So I put this in production.rb:

config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/myapp"

I put this in routes:

```
 scope "/myapp" do
    root :to => 'application#index'
    match 'login/index' => 'logins#index',        :as => 'logins_index'
  end
```

In my form tag, I have:

```
<form class="loginForm" name="loginForm" id="loginForm" action="<%= url_for('/login') %>" method="post">
```

I thought that everything would magically work, but in fact I needed to put

```
 action="<%= url_for('/myapp/login') %>"
```

To get it to work.  Is this expected? I don't want to have to worry about where my app is getting placed for production, but this solution requires it to be in my code.  thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined helper `logins_index_xxx` (where `xxx` can be `path` or `url`) but you don't use it. Why? Try this:

```
... action="<%= logins_index_path %>" ...
```