# Redmine 2.3 relative url root not working with Apache mod_proxy

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, apache2, redmine, mod-proxy, mod-proxy-balancer

I am currently attempting to upgrade from Redmine 1.4 (based on Rails 2.3) to Redmine 2.3 (Rails 3.2).  I am forced to use Apache with mod_proxy and proxy balancer, so any talk of passenger is out.  I am trying to deploy Redmine on a sub-uri (https://mysite.com/redmine).  The current Apache config is as follows:

```
ProxyPass /redmine balancer://redmine_cluster
ProxyPassReverse /redmine balancer://redmine_cluster

<Proxy balancer://redmine_cluster>
  Order allow,deny
  Allow from all
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:9000
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:9001
  BalancerMember http://127.0.0.1:9002
</Proxy>
```

I used to be able to use Redmine::Utils.relative_url_root="/redmine" to handle url_for and link_to, but that no longer works.

I have tried the following:

1. Editing config.ru

   map ActionController::Base.config.relative_url_root || "/" do
       run RedmineApp::Application
      end
2. Running rails with: RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT='/redmine' script/rails s -p 9000
3. Adding config.action_controller.relative_url_root = "/forge" to application.rb

I cannot figure what needs to be done.  Any help would be great.  Thank you.

Comment: Now there seems a useful [SO entry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181746/what-is-the-replacement-for-actioncontrollerbase-relative-url-root/5457484#5457484)