# Rails configure application to have url prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I feel like this should not be all that difficult, but I cannot find any solutions that seem to work with Rails4

#### My setup

- I have a proxy server ([Kong](http://getkong.org)) that directs to various services behind it based on path.

  - `myapp.com/app1/` is redirected to `http://app1_address:PORT/` (notice `/app1` is stripped)
  - same for `myapp.com/app2`

`app2` is a Rails 4 application and it works just fine when browsing to specific, but its relative routing is completely off. For example, `link_to` or `url_for` links to controllers or actions all redirect to the wrong links.

For example, I have a logout link that has a path of `/logout` on `app2`, but redirecting the user to `/logout` is incorrect. They need to be routed to `/app2/logout`. How can I configure the Rails app to add a prefix to all routes?

#### I have tried:

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/app2'
```

As well as this:

```
config.relative_url_root = '/app2'
```

And this in `config.ru`

```
map <MyAppName>::Application.config.relative_url_root || "/" do
  run Rails.application
end
```

Any ideas for how to make this work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the replacement for ActionController::Base.relative\_url\_root?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181746/what-is-the-replacement-for-actioncontrollerbase-relative-url-root)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a scope in your routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  scope ENV["PROXY_PATH"] do 
    # your routes..
  end
end
```

This way you'll have to set the ENV variable:

```
$ export PROXY_PATH=app2
$ bin/rails s
```

Comment: This isn't what I'm looking for, as the code I posted in the original question accomplishes the same thing but leaves the routes file unmodified. The reason this doesn't work is that it assumes the requests are prefixed by `/app`, but the proxy server strips the route prefix before forwarding the request. So a request to `/app` appears simply as `/`. As a temporary workaround I disabled this route stripping and left the code from my example above